# Converting a cross-referenced matrix in excel into a Python array(s) for a 3D plot

Tags: python, excel, python-3.x, numpy, matplotlib

```
     x1   x2    x3
y1   z1   z2    z3
y2   z4   z5    z6
y3   z7   z8    z9
```

If I have a cross referenced matrix of values(in Excel) as above, what's the best way to create a 3D array or other data structure in Python that could be plotted as a wireframe in matplotlib?

[Example matrix](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S4NH7.png)

EDIT: I ended up using MatLab:

```
[D,S,R] = xlsread('matrix.xlsx');
Z = D(2:end,2:end);
M = max(max(Z));
figure(1)
X = D(1,2:end);
Y = D(2:end,1);
x1 = min(X);
x2 = max(X);
y1 = min(Y);
y2 = max(Y);
mesh(X,Y,Z)
```

Answer (score -1):

I do not have much time right now but this is how I would do it.

Save to csv read data into python with pandas. There are tons of examples for this.

[Here is one.](https://chrisalbon.com/python/data_wrangling/pandas_dataframe_importing_csv/)

Arrange data to fit like it does in this matplotlib 3D wire frame example.

[matplotlib wire3d](https://matplotlib.org/examples/mplot3d/wire3d_demo.html)

Hope this helps get you in the right direction.